# access numpy array from a functional language

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming, numpy, scipy

My primary language is Python. Often when I need to do some cpu heavy task on a numpy array I use scipy.weave.inline to hook up c++ with great results.

I suspect many of the algorithms (machine learning stuff) can however be written simpler in a functional language (scheme, haskell...).

I was thinking. Is it possible to access numpy array data (read and write) from a functional language instead of having to use c++?

Comment: I meant accessing it in memory, but for small arrays / heavy processing it might be sufficient to save it from python to disk (or /dev/shm), load it in haskell, process, save to disk, load from python.

Comment: @janto - Sorry, I deleted my comment about the same time you replied... In retrospect, I figured it seemed obvious that you meant accessing it in memory.  At any rate, as my answer below elaborates on a bit, one solution would be to use a shared memory buffer for the numpy array, and then access it from your haskell (or whatever) process... This does add an additional layer of complexity compared to weave, etc, though...

Comment: @janto: Have you taken a look at the various python machine learning packages? There might be fast solutions or templates for writing your own already available in python.

Comment: Incidentally, a bit of googling seems to indicate that haskell can interface with C libraries and vice-versa via the FFI: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_Introduction (I'm not a haskell person, so forgive me if this is completely off-base!).  If you can call a haskell routine from C, then you can call it from python through ctypes, cython, weave, etc...  It might be a pain, but it sounds possible. It's "just" a matter of handling the memory buffer that a numpy array is stored in...

Comment: @JashAdel The algorithms I'm looking at are less popular (compared to things like SVMs) and research is still on going. So there aren't even a lot of C implementations of the things I do (belief propagation, pseudo likelihoods).

Comment: @Joe-Kington I'm also not a haskell person. Thanks. Interesting idea. Yes, sounds like a lot of work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have a look at using a shared-memory array of some sort.  This implementation would probably be a good place to start: https://bitbucket.org/cleemesser/numpy-sharedmem/src

This implementation is intended to be shared between python processes, but it's using named shared memory to do it, so you should be able to access the relevant chunk of memory from any other process.

I'm not familiar enough with haskell to give you any advice on that side, but I assume you can use a pointer to a shared memory buffer as an array of some sort in haskell...

Comment: This may be the simplest approach.  It would be relatively easy to create a Haskell process that operates on a shared memory buffer.  The module `Data.Vector.Storable` from the vector package would provide this for 1D arrays (for higher dimensions, maybe hmatrix would work).

Answer (score 4):

There's no single standard way to call Haskell from Python at the moment. There are certainly ways to call haskell from C, which means there's no obstacle in principle to calling Haskell -- the work simply hasn't been done to make this particularly easy.

On the other hand, if your data structures aren't themselves enormous, serializing them to a Haskell program (either via the command line, or using, a client-server model with e.g. thrift) is very straightforward, and if the computation cost is what sufficiently dominates, the cost may be minimal.

Finally, it is very easy to call Python from Haskell! The classic package for this is missingpy: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MissingPy

There's also a newer package called cpython which attempts to be more comprehensive: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cpython

Conceptually, it shouldn't be very hard, I imagine, to host your Python app in Haskell rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have no requirements on the platform to use, you might take a look at the Numpy implementation for .NET and IronPython running on CLI. With this you'll be able to use F# as a functional language for instance. Some details to Numpy and Scipy on .NET are [here](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net) and a list of [CLI languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages).

Answer (score -2):

I can't imagine trying to use numpy through haskell or scheme will be easier than just writing functional python.  Try using `itertools` and `functools` if you want a more functional flavored python.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, and I understand the sentiment, but it's a valid question and deserves an actual answer regardless of whether you agree with the motivation. Somethling like this belongs in a comment.

Comment: The problem is speed. Python is way too slow for the types of algorithms I run. I am under the impression I could write a function in, say, Haskell and have it run as fast as or even faster than c++.

Comment: I will be shocked if anyone comes up with a way to access numpy in haskell or scheme that has more practical utility than optimizing your python code or just switching to a different programming language.  I realize it doesn't answer the question directly, but my answer is still "You're taking the wrong approach."

Comment: Well, unfortunately there is just no way Python can (sans cython or PyPy) compete with the c++ code. Also completely switching to a different language won't work. I have a lot of data that needs to be processed and Python is perfect for that (glue language etc).

Comment: If you have the algorithm implemented in C++, call your C++ code from Python using cython.  My recommendation is to _not_ re-implement your code in Haskell or Lisp (or even Python) but use it directly.

Comment: I think I'm not making my situation clear. I already have c++ code and am already calling it from python via scipy.weave. It's fast enough and interfaces with my numpy arrays. I am merely wondering if it is possible to use a functional language instead of c++ to do the same, as I suspect the algorithm would be cleaner in a functional language. Sorry if there is any confusion.